# Mac continued to restart while booting

Tags: macos, restart

My Mac displays the log in screen for entering password, but after entering and when the progress bar hits around 40% it will show the “your Mac will restart because of some problems...” and when it restart it will again enter this status, so it is like a never ending loop.

This might be a problem: hard drive only have 8.7 MB free space.

Comment: Try https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the low disk space. After deleting the Window Boot-Camp which provide an extra 64GB on disk, my Mac successfully booted.